# What's wrong with this part of htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, laravel

For a customer of mine I'm building a website. For this I use the Laravel framework.
Now I know the best practice is to set the public directory as DocumentRoot, but the problem is, I can't.
So I've done some research, and I saw that you could use .htaccess to handle this little problem.
The snippet that's on the laravel forums is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I try this, I get a 500 Internal Server error.
I found that the problem was the `(.*)` part of the fourth line... But I just can't see what's wrong with it.

So does anybody know what's wrong with this snippet, why am I getting a 500 error...

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. [`REQUEST_URI`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) includes the leading slash `/`. So you must say

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the *public* folder path, just copy the usual laravel tree and use the following in 
**/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This worked for me on L3.